# Question about parenting armature and body parts in 2D animation Blender

Tags: animation

I have a doubt about 2D animation in Blender, as a beginner I need lot of suggestions please help me. After rigging the human body parts, parts should be parented to that particular armature or it has to be parented to the body.If it is parented to armature animation of body parts is not proper. If parented to body then there is no connection to armature and the model gets spoiled by keeping poses with the pivot point.Can any one tell me what to do? and how to do?

Comment: Could you add screenshots of your problem and upload the .blend file to help you solve you problem?

Comment: how to upload file and add screenshots

Comment: You can upload you blend file as shown here http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/659/2517 and add a photo as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcm8C.png